# why expo access denied for link given for my apk?

Tags: apk, expo

Firstly, I should confess that it is not easy at all using expo with react native for building your project , after hours of trying generating my APK , finally, I got my APK , but the link given is not working , saying :

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>6FEF3FBBB0457899</RequestId>
<HostId>
```

any idea?

Comment: Please create an [mcve] where this error also occurs.